# How to close Excel sheet opened using Oledb.oledbconnection

Tags: vb.net

I have a program written in VB.NET where I open an Excel workbook to read in data to insert into a SQL server database. I do a while rs.read and set variables to be inserted into the database. My issue is that (when I finished loading the data into the database) I have tried several ways to close the Excel sheet but it remains open.

Here is the code:

```
Using myExcel As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ImportDirectory & ImportFile & ImportFileExtension & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES""")
    myExcel.Open()
    Dim myQuery As String = "select * from [Sheet1$]"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(myQuery, myExcel)
    Dim rd As OleDbDataReader
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While rd.Read
        Cnumber = rd.Item(0).ToString
        Cname = rd.Item(1).ToString
        Cadd1 = rd.Item(2).ToString
        Cadd2 = rd.Item(3).ToString
        Ccity = rd.Item(4).ToString
        Cstate = rd.Item(5).ToString
        Czip = rd.Item(6).ToString
        Ctyp = rd.Item(7).ToString

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.ConnectionString = ConnectionStr
            con.Open()
        End If
        With sqlCommand
            .Connection = con
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "dbo.InsertCustomers"
            .Parameters.Clear()
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cnum", Cnumber)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cname", Cname)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add1", Cadd1)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add2", Cadd2)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", Ccity)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", Cstate)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", Czip)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", Ctyp)
            Try
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                objWriter.WriteLine(ln & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End With
    Loop
    rd.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    myExcel.Close()
    myExcel.Dispose()


End Using
```

I know I can spin through all processes to kill Excel but the user may have other files open. I only want to close the file I am currently working with. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: not directly related to the question, but you may want to have a look at this: http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: You should add a Using block for your reader. I think your End Using should take care of your concerns.